# Question about bevel

Tags: bevel

Bevel makes the "distances" between the vertices always larger-looking.
Images:

Thank you for your help

[image]

[image: Preview of my problem:]

Comment: I don't think there's any direct way to do it, you can do it indirectly, for example use a Solidify modifier, or extrude along faces normal, or Scale down if the faces already exist, etc

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I just wanted to ask, but my current methods are the following:
1.) Shrink/Fatten
2.) Extrude along Normal-Faces
3.) Spin

Thank you again :)

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos I changed my describtion. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Not great, compared to a dedicated tool, but..

If, one way or another, you can arrange for equidistant 'stopping' edges on either side of the vertex to be bevelled, then you can take your bevel as far as it will go, with shape 0.5, and 'Clamp Overlap' switched off.

For example, if you've got a lot of arcs to make to a known radius, you could Knife Project the limiting edges, using a pre-prepared jig...

[image]

.. followed by <kbd>M</kbd> Merge > By Distance.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that next time. It's helpful when you've already extruded the face before beveling.